# CNTK (Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit) ImportError

Tags: python, machine-learning, cntk

Code:

```
import cntk
n = cntk.minus([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).eval()
print(n)
```

Problem:

> If run the code line by line in python command line, it's ok.
>
> If run "Python main.py", it's also ok.
>
> But if run the code in PyCharm or Visual Studio Code, error occurs, PyCharm error dump:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
  return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dev/machine_learning/Test_CNTK/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cntk
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\site-packages\cntk\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\site-packages\cntk\core.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import cntk_py
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 21, in <module>
    _cntk_py = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')
  File "D:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.53\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Environment:

- Anaconda: 4.3.1
- Python: 3.5.3 (virtual environment in anaconda)
- CNTK: 2.0beta12 for windows amd64 GPU
- PyCharm: 2016.3.2
- Visual Studio Code: 1.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

Because it can't find the DLL files with CNTK (e.g. CNTKLibrary-2.0.dll, EvalDll.dll), these DLLs are in the same directory of "python.exe" after installation of CNTK.

There are 2 solutions:

(suppose the PYTHONDIR is the directory where python.exe is in)

1. change the system environment PATH to include PYTHONDIR
2. add the following code before "import cntk":

   import os; os.environ['PATH'] = PYTHONDIR + ';' + os.environ['PATH']